# Set page counter to account for implicit omitted pages

Tags: page-numbering, etoolbox

I recently added an `etoolbox` toggle to let me choose between the paper or electronic versions of my document.

```
\newtoggle{papier}
```

Primarily, this disables coloured hyperlinks and coloured code using the package `listings`. In the paper version, I normally use the following function

```
\newcommand\sautdoublepage{\clearpage{~\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
```

before each new chapter to leave the left page empty. I am tempted to disable it for the electronic version as it does have any meaning to keep it (Like in the MWE), but I end up with different page numberings between my electronic and paper versions.

So my question is: is there a way to define `\sautdoublepage` so it sets the page counter to the value it would have had if `\sautdoublepage` has been defined like in the paper version.

I am not sure this is clear, so here is an illustration of what I would like to do

**Paper version**

Page 1 - Chapter 1;
Page 2 - Skipped page;
Page 3 - Chapter 2;
...

**Current electronic version**

Page 1 - Chapter 1;
Page 2 - Chapter 2;
...

**Desired electronic version**

Page 1 - Chapter 1;
Page 3 - Chapter 2;
...

*The MWE:*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,%
            bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\newtoggle{papier}
\toggletrue{papier}

\iftoggle{papier}{% Paper
\newcommand\sautdoublepage{\clearpage{~\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
}{% Electronic
\newcommand\sautdoublepage{}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\sautdoublepage\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[4-15]
\sautdoublepage\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[16-40]
\sautdoublepage\chapter*{Last chapter}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I find your `\sautdoublepage` macro to be weird. It may, in certain instances, leave 3 blank pages.

Comment: @Werner It is so to have all new chapters starting on an odd page, with the previous page, in front, being empty. `\cleardoublepage` only garantees that a new chapter starts on an odd page. The whole document looks more "aired" once printed.

Comment: Aired indeed, with possibly 3 blank pages in front of some chapters. If I had that much blank space before a chapter, I would consider it a misprint.

Comment: I do not know what to tell you, it is very common in books to leave the page before a chapter empty and I am writting a very long document. One to three pages a chapter left empty is nothing compared to the currently ~350 full of text pages I have. Also, I normally use `\pagestyle{plain}` on skipped pages to keep page numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `\ifoddpage` from the `changepage` package to detect when you want to skip a page number.

```
\newcommand\sautdoublepage{\clearpage\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\addtocounter{page}{2}\else\addtocounter{page}{1}\fi}
```

which with `\togglefalse{papier}` yields Chapter 2 starting from Page 3:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,%
            bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newtoggle{papier}
\togglefalse{papier}


\iftoggle{papier}{% Paper
    \newcommand\sautdoublepage{\clearpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}%
}{% Electronic
    \newcommand\sautdoublepage{\clearpage\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\addtocounter{page}{2}\else\addtocounter{page}{1}\fi}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\sautdoublepage\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[4-15]
\sautdoublepage\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[16-40]
\sautdoublepage\chapter*{Last chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed, but this works between chapter 1 and 2, not between chapter 2 and 3. I tried `\sautdoublepage{\clearpage\ifoddpage\addtocounter{page}{3}\else\addtocounter{page}{1}\fi}` instead, but it seems to consider that chapter 2 finishes on an odd-numbered page whereas it finishes on an even-numbered page. Would you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Opps. Forgot to invoke `\checkoddpage`. New version has the chapters in the MWE all starting on an odd page.

Comment: Perfect, this does work ! I added `\addtocounter{page}{2}` to your answer so page numberings are identical between the electronic and paper versions.